# Let $f:R\longrightarrow S$ be a surjective ring homomorphism. If $R$ is PID, then $S$ is PIR.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Let $f:R\longrightarrow S$ be a surjective ring homomorphism. If $R$ is PID, then $S$ is PIR.

I think I have proved this:

Let $J$ be an ideal of $S$. Then $f^{-1}(J)=(a)$ is a principal ideal of $R$. Hence $J=f (f^{-1}(J))=f((a))=(f(a))$ is a principal ideal of $S$. Is my proof correct?

But I also think there are some counterexamples by considering the quotient rings of polynomial rings $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/f(x,y)$. I am confused...

Comment: The proof is correct, and $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ is not a PID, if that is what is confusing you.

Comment: The proof is "correct", but the claim is obviously false! Take $R=\Bbb Z$.

Comment: The proof is correct but $Z[x,y]$ is not a *PID*, see  
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697204/is-any-ufd-also-a-pid/701581#701581

Answer (score 3):

*This is a community wiki answer designed to help eliminate this question from the unanswered queue*

---

The proof has been verified to be correct.

The example given is not a counterexample since $\mathbb Z[x, y]$ is not a principal ideal domain.