# Is any UFD also a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

Is there any counterexample that will disprove that every **unique factorization domain** (UFD) is also a **principal ideal domain** (PID)? I mean, any PID is a UFD, does the converse hold?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\mathbb C[x, y]$ is a UFD but not a PID.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is another common example of a UFD that is not a PID.

Comment: PID = UFD of dimension 1 (i.e. non-zero prime ideals are maximal).

Comment: See this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16754/unique-factorization-domain-that-is-not-a-principal-ideal-domain

Comment: This Q is surely a duplicate. Perhaps someone can find a link (including the standard example $K[x,y]$).

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/78006/173147

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A *PID* is always of *dim* $1$. So you can find a lot of *UFD*'s that are not *PID*; for example:
 Every polynomial ring in more than one variable with coeffcients in a field.
 Every *regular local* ring of *dim* greater than $1$ (i.e the maximal ideal can not generated with one element).